# Why is std::basic_string::operator[] simultaneously a const/non-const member function?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, overloading, std, function-qualifier

http://cplusplus.com/reference/string/basic_string/operator[]

I understand that it's advantageous to have a second version which returns `const` to prevent warnings when a `const` result is required and to mitigate casting but if the function already provides a non-`const` method (method-- not result) then what is the point of declaring the `const`-result method `const`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to understand, that the second (`const`) version not only *returns* a different result but is also marked itself as `const` (this is the second `const` at the end of the declaration):

```
const_reference operator[] (size_type pos) const;
```

These are two different things: The `const` return value by itself would not be needed in the presence of a non-`const` method (since the non-const return value can always be casted tò the `const` version).

But not having a `const`-version of the operator would mean, that you couldn't use it on `const` string objects.

The `const` result is just a result of the `const`ness of the operator itself: if you have a `const` string and use the operator to get a reference to a single character, clearly this reference must also be `const` (if not, you could change single characters within a `const` string).

Comment: OH OF COURSE! It's referring to the object itself being const. This the allows filtering methods for the same type of object which is either `const` or non-`const`. This is the clue I was missing. Having been programming in Java for a while, I'd forgotten that this is how we deal with immutable types without having to create a duplicate "immutable" class of the same object.

Answer (score 3):

Assume you have

```
const std::string str{"test"};
std::cout << str[2];
```

If you don't have a `const` member function, the code above will fail, as the `this` pointer passed implicitly to `operator[]` is `const`.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a `const std::basic_string` you cannot call (non-const) `std::basic_string::operator[]`, as it is, well, not marked const.

Answer (score 1):

If there wasn't a `const` version of the function, the function could not be invoked on a `const` instance. For example:

```
void func (const std::string &h)
{
    if (h[0] == "hello")
        ...
}
```

How would this work if there wasn't a `const` version of `operator[]`?

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but maybe the typo or maybe someone thought it was incomplete (`if (h[0] ==`)?

Answer (score 0):

The `const` method returns a different type, it returns a `const`-qualified reference. This means if the `const` method is used, the result of the method is `const`-qualified (and therefore is “immutable”). The non-`const`-qualified method returns a regular reference, which is “mutable”.

You can't have *just* the `const` method or else you can't modify individual characters in non-`const`-qualified `std::basic_string` objects. And you can't have *just* the non-`const` method or you won't be able to call the method on `const`-qualifed `std::basic_string` objects.