# Does a const member function call the non-const version, or is it recursive?

Tags: c++, recursion, constants, const-correctness, function-qualifier

For defining a second `const` version of a function, is it guaranteed safe to do this? It looks like it would have infinite recursion as I want to return `const` but the other function which I mean to call is non-const.

It works with g++ but I worry that this is unsafe.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class test {
public:
   int* doSomething(int a) {
      int* someInt = new int(a);

      return someInt;
   }

   const int* doSomething(int a) const {
      return doSomething(a);
   }
};

int main() {
   test a;

   cout << *a.doSomething(12345) << endl;

   return 1;
}
```

Comment: This code calls the non-const version of `doSomething`. Try calling the const version and watch it blow up.

Comment: Why don't you just initialize `someInt` when allocating it: `int* someInt = new int(a);`

Comment: i always thought c++ doesnt allow overloading of functions that only differ in return type....

Comment: @Anedar: The overload doesn't only differ in return type. It also has different cv-qualification.

Comment: @Anedar - it doesn't. But that's not the case here; the two functions differ in their `const` qualifiers, which determines which one can be called on a const object and which one on a non-const object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not quite: as @Pete Becker has pointed out in the comments, if you had called the `const` version that **will** recurse:

```
class test {
public:
   int* doSomething(int a) {
      int* someInt = new int;
      *someInt = a;
      return someInt;
   }

   const int* doSomething(int a) const {
      return doSomething(a);
   }
};

int main() {
   const test a;
   // You're not in for a good time:
   a.doSomething(12345);
   return 1;
}
```

When providing `const` and non-`const` versions of a function that requires duplicated code, it's best to implement the `const` version, then have the non-`const` version call it in a specific way.

From Scott Myers [Effective C++ - Third Edition](http://www.aristeia.com/books.html):

> When `const` and non-`const` member functions have essentially identical implementation, code duplication can be avoided by having the non-`const` version call the `const` version

Scott Myers goes on to provide a safe means for doing this:

```
const int* doSomething(int a) const
{
   int* someInt = new int;
   *someInt = a;
   return someInt;
}

int* doSomething(int a)
{
   return const_cast<int*>(static_cast<const Test&>(*this).doSomething());
}
```

In the non-`const` version, there are two casts: the `static_cast` basically turns `this` into `const this`, where the `const_cast` casts away the `const`-ness of the return. This is safe to do, because to call the non-`const` version, you must've had a non-`const this`.

However, if you are just providing access to a member, it's simple and easier to read to just have the following:

```
class TestAccess;
class Test
{
    TestAccess& t;
public:
    const TestAccess& getA() const { return t; }
    TestAcess& getA() { return t; }
};
```

Comment: Scott Myers's solution is perfect. I was trying to think if there was a way to call the non-`const` version in some way from the `const` one, which I don't think you can. Thank you for explaining this clearly. Part of the problem was my misunderstanding of how a const method works: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34983475/why-is-stdbasic-stringoperator-a-const-method-if-its-also-a-non-const-met?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: Any caveats to having the `const` version call a non-`const` version? Seems to work OK.

Comment: Yes: a `const`  member function promises to never change the state of an object, but you'd essentially be calling a non-`const` function which could alter the state of the object. It's safer to have the non-`const` version call the `const` version, as a non-`const` function can do whatever it wants to an object.

Comment: You're right but from the perspective of simply removing duplicate code it shouldn't make a difference. I do something like this: `u8char_t* codepoint = &_base[0];` which when called from a const method throws an error unless I remove the const with a static cast. I felt that if I were doing that then I may as well just have call the non-`const` version from the `const` one and forego the cast. To clarify, I use `codepoint` to iterate over the base string with `codepoint + length` where `length` is the width of the utf-8 character in bytes.

Answer (score 0):

In this case the compiler is always going to pick the not const version of the function, is not even calling the const one.
Otherwise the compiler will not compile, you are braking the constenss.
For example I modified quickly the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class test {
public:
    int* doSomething(int a) {
        int* someInt = new int;

        *someInt = a;
        return someInt;
    }
    int ax = 10;
    void somethingElse(int i)
    {
        ax = i;
    }
    const int* doSomething(int a) const {
        somethingElse(a);
        return 0;
    }
};

int main() {
    test a;

    cout << *a.doSomething(12345) << endl;

    return 1;
}
```

This example does not compile because you are calling a const function inside a const scope. The compiler won't let you do that.

Now, I know is a test but doing this way you will never get out of the recursion, it will loop forever, and also you are leaking memory at every call by allocating on the heap, those two things together can lead to a disaster.

Comment: I know it's leaking memory. It's is just an example.

Comment: Out of curiosity of your coding style, is the closing brace of `somethingElse()` indented 8 spaces for a reason or is this a mistake?

Comment: you could just return the int itself, even for a test don't see why you need a leaking pointer. Anyway not the point.

About parenthesis, yep mistake, I quickly coded it and must have been messed up in the copy pasting
Cheers

M.

Comment: G++ was yelling at me saying `warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type` so I switched it to a pointer. It could be const but the result is a native type and always passed by value; so the `const` is moot.

Comment: You can pass pointer and references to native types. but usually, unless there is a good reason for that, you should try to avoid it, just because you are using more memory then you should, on a 64 bit machine a pointer or ref to an int is 64 bit, meanwhile the int itself is most likely 32 bit. But if you have multiple arguments you use to return values then you can use a ref or pointer to native types.